# how to run URL to linking css and js in https laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run `URL::to` over `HTTPS` like secure_asset but I want `URL::to` to run over `https` can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mix to create this assets, the you have to use `mix()` instead of `url()`... And if you are not using mix, uset `asset()`.

Also, explain a lottle bit more why are you using those functions you mentioned to link assets instead of the ones I have shared right now...

Comment: I use them because some times this functions doesn't work like in subfolders

Comment: Explain more, as those functions alwyas work, you are doing something wrong, so please expalin more